# android - How to add a NavigationDrawer within an activity that has a BottomNavigationBar with just one Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity, bottomnavigationview

I have a MainActivity contains:

1- `BottomNavigationBar` and 5 tabs with 5 fragments.

2- main theme **NoActionBar**.

3- each fragment has a layout with its own `Toolbar` and different `title`.

Now i want to add a `NavigationDrawer` in the MainActivity and only one ActionBar that cantains (the Title of the Fragment of the BottomNavigationBar's tab & the NavDrawer icon button) thats all in **one** ActionBar.
this image is define the issue i have:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you only want to show a title and icon on the fragments toolbars, then there's no need for a toolbar for each fragment. just use the one in the main activivy and change the title and the icon when the tab gets changed.

using this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 public BottomBar bottomBar;
 private Toolbar toolbar;
 private ImageView toolbarIcon;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(" "); 

    bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
          @Override
          public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

            switch (tabId) {
              case R.id.tab1: 
                TabOne tabOne= new TabOne();
                commitFragment(tabOne);
                toolbar.setTitle("Tab One");
                toolbarIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_tab_1));
                break;

              case R.id.tab1: 
                TabTwo tabTwo= new TabTwo ();
                commitFragment(tabTwo);
                toolbar.setTitle("Tab Two");
                toolbarIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_tab_2));
                break;

               // and so on....
            }
          }
        });
     }
   }
```

And add an `ImageView` inside the toolbar to better control the changes.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```